# Fetch one row from MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, tkinter

I'm trying to fetch one row of a MySQL table based on a user input. My code is:

```
"""Get entry information"""
            reinforcement_name = reinforcement_input.get()

"""Fetch reinforcement data"""
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            sql_select_query = "select '*' from reinforcement where name = '%s'"
            mycursor.execute(sql_select_query, reinforcement_name)
            reinforcement_data = mycursor.fetchone()

            print(reinforcement_data)
```

I'm expecting to get a list of column entries for that specific user input. However, I'm getting `None` printed out rather than a list.

How can I have my `reinforcement_data` presented as the list I'm expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchone` call is OK. The problem is with your query - when you use a parameterized query, you should **not** use quotes around the bind variables - these aren't simple string replacements, but bind variables the database driver handles. Here, you're querying for a row with the literal name of `%s`, which probably doesn't exist. The parameters need to pass to `execute` as an iterable.

On a related note, you should also remove the quotes around the `*` in the select list, otherwise, you'll get the asterisk literal, not all the columns.

```py
sql_select_query = "select * from reinforcement where name = %s"
# No quotes --------------^-^-------------------------------^--^

mycursor.execute(sql_select_query, (reinforcement_name,))
# Params passed as a tuple --------^
```

Comment: I changed the syntax as I kept getting the following error without the quotes around %s:


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1.


Any idea why I'm getting the syntax error?

Comment: @JosephJoeSoltan I missed that you weren't using a tuple for the params. See my edited answer